# Calculate selected table values (knockout, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Looking for some advice.

I am trying to create a dynamic table with knockout (it's great but I'm only on first steps of it).
This table works, but I still get some issues:
1. (update: deleted)
2. self.ave returns NaN, not an calculated average weight of selected risks;

```
self.ave = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.risks().length; i++) {
        total += self.risks()[i].weight;
    }
    return total/self.risks().length;
});
```

Update: It seems, that every time I add new Risk, the weight of it is 0. Also sum of all risks is calculated as 1 (weight of default risk) + 0(weight of any of new risk) + 0 +n...

update2: still looking for any help
http://jsfiddle.net/Skaidrius/52xdL/

Comment: Still can not find out how to calculate total and average weight of selected risks of some Activity.

Answer (score 1):

there are some minor mistakes.

1. For first problem- availableRisks should not be common it should be attached with Activity.

   ```
   var Activity = function (title) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.availableRisks = ko.observableArray([{
      name: "Low",
      weight: 1
    }, {
     name: "Medium",
     weight: 2
    }, {
     name: "High",
     weight: 3
    }]);
   };
   ```

2- self.risks()[i].weight is observable so access it with parenthesis.

```
self.ave = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < self.risks().length; i++) {
        total += self.risks()[i].weight();
    }
   return total/self.risks().length || 0;
});
```

change binding in view for availableRisks

```
<!-- ko foreach:risks -->
        <td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: $parent.availableRisks, value: risks.weight, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5Crd/6/)

Comment: Thank you so much. self.ave still do not calculates average weight, but it is now far better than was before. Also, would you mind to explain why it is necessary to add availableRisks to Activity and not to Risk class.

Comment: because availablerisk is distinct for each row so if it will be shared then you will get same value. there is another way also you can have self.risks in Activity instead of availableRisk. both will work